# How can I get data attribute value of clicked button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset

I want to get data attribute value of clicked button. I need to use it When I submit an ajax form. How can I get that ?

My button (There are as many buttons as the number of products)

```
<input value="Add To Cart" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block add-to-card-button" data-id="{{$product->id}}" style="margin-bottom:10px">
```

Javascript codes;

```
const cartButton = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-card-button');

if (cartButton) {
    Array.from(cartButton).forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', addToCard);
    });
   }

function addToCard() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/auth/check",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(status){
           if (status === "Auth")
           {
               addToCardForUsers();
           } else {
               addToCardForGuests()
           }
        }
    });

}

function addToCardForUsers() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/cart/add-product/"+ cartButton.dataset.id,
        context: document.body,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(){
                if(countProduct.text() == null) {
                    countProduct.text(1);
                } else {
                    countProducts =  Number(countProduct.text());
                    countProducts++;
                    countProduct.text(countProducts);
                }              
                Flash.success("Product succesfully added to your cart");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try,  alert($(this).data('data-id'));

Comment: gives undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
function addToCard(e) {
    alert($(e.target).data('id'))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the way you bind your event listner to this,

```
$('.add-to-card-button').on('click', function () {
    addToCard();
    alert($(this).data('id'));
});
```

Comment: Sorry, again my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is grab the id in `addToCart` and pass that as a parameter to `addToCardForUsers` where you can use it in your endpoint string. And since you're using jQuery, perhaps use it to pick up the buttons and assign the function to them on the click event.

```
$('add-to-card-button').on('click', addToCart);

function addToCard() {
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/auth/check",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(status) {
      if (status === "Auth") {
        addToCardForUsers(id);
      } else {
        addToCardForGuests()
      }
    }
  });
}

function addToCardForUsers(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/cart/add-product/" + id,
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Well.. let me confess.. I couldn't even think about it :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input value="Add To Cart" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block add-to-card-button" data-id="{{$product->id}}" style="margin-bottom:10px">
```

To get the data-id attribute value from above code on button click event:

```
$(this).data('id')
```

JSFiddler Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/682xdbkv/1/

Comment: gives undefined :(

Comment: I have added JSFiddler demo in the answer. Please refer it. To check it further, please share the HTML code generated

Comment: demo works fine but I cant understand.. I'm checking my codes, everything seems same :/